How to capture raw audio from just_audio AudioPlayer?
How can I capture the raw audio from just_audio AudioPlayer?
I've been using the native Audio Playback Capture API, and it works great, but the individual volumes of each AudioPlayer is ignored. So if I have a volume control in the app, it's ignored and still plays at 100% in the captured raw data, which is different from the actual audio output of the app.
